# Вк бот не принимает сообщения из другой беседы

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Бот может отвечать на сообщения в лс и беседы группы бота, но при добавлении в другую беседы он не отправляет сообщения и не выводит никаких результатов от лонгпулла.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import 
VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = 
vk_api.VkApi(token)
vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.NEW_MESSAGE and event.text:
         if event.from_chat: 
vk_session.messages.send(peer_id=event.peer_id,message="Проверка", random_id=0)
```

Тоже самое будет, если использовать VkBotLongPoll, толькон он уже перестанет отвечать везде

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто поменять версию API на 5.101. >:(